# Calculate row mean excuding outliers in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple rows and columns. I have calculated the mean of every row and added this as a column. I would like to create another column of the mean of every row excluding outliers (values outside 1 standard deviation from the mean of that row).

This is how my dataframe `a` looks like:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | Mean value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1034.3704 | 1068.1960 | **1243.7016** | 1057.1152 | 1026.4972 |
| 1 | 1042.5352 | 1071.6952 | 1052.1580 | 1020.6652 | **1534.9536** |
| 2 | 1013.0836 | **1819.7904** | 1022.1232 | 1030.5796 | 1036.4116 |
| 3 | 1043.4100 | 1069.9456 | 1015.1248 | 1026.2056 | 1034.9536 |

I tried the following:

```
def reject_outliers(data):
    m = 2 
    u = np.mean(data.T[0:5]) 
    s = np.std(data.T[0:5]) 
    filtered = [e for e in data.T[0:5] if (u - 2 * s < e < u + 2 * s)] 
    return filtered
```

However this throws errors for me:

```
ValueError: the truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: There are **tons** of different methods to do this. Please provide at least the desired method and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I want to use the standard deviation to identify my outliers, remove them and then calculate the mean again

Comment: `m=2 u` is invalid code. what's u? is this 2 multiplying u? if so, why there's no multiplication operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it by calculating the row-wise mean and standard deviation, then setting values outside 1 standard deviation from the mean to NaN, and calculating the mean of the non-NaN values:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create an example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 5)), columns=[0,1,2,3,4])

# Calculate mean and std columns
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
df['std'] = df.loc[:,[0,1,2,3,4]].std(axis=1)

# Create boolean array of outliers
outliers = (df.loc[:,[0,1,2,3,4]] > np.tile(df['mean']+df['std'], (5,1)).T) | (df.loc[:,[0,1,2,3,4]] < np.tile(df['mean']-df['std'], (5,1)).T)
# Set outliers to NaN
df[outliers] = pd.NA
# Calculate new mean, ignoring NaNs
df['mean-no-outliers'] = df.loc[:,[0,1,2,3,4]].mean(axis=1, skipna=True)
```

This gives me a dataframe, `df`, like this (but your randomly initiated array will contain different values):

```
      0     1     2     3     4  mean        std  mean-no-outliers
0  47.0  38.0   NaN   6.0   NaN  36.2  36.182869         30.333333
1   NaN  77.0  87.0   NaN  97.0  53.8  46.056487         87.000000
2  72.0   NaN  59.0   NaN  60.0  63.8   8.729261         63.666667
3  27.0   NaN  34.0  13.0  22.0  32.4  20.280533         24.000000
4  43.0  78.0  97.0  89.0   NaN  66.6  30.664312         76.750000
5   6.0   NaN   5.0  26.0   6.0  15.2  13.292855         10.750000
6  36.0   NaN   NaN  33.0   NaN  47.2  25.302174         34.500000
7  11.0   NaN   8.0   8.0   8.0  16.2  16.709279          8.750000
8   NaN  28.0  41.0   NaN  40.0  37.2  16.754104         36.333333
9  55.0  67.0  64.0   NaN  34.0  48.6  19.269146         55.000000
```